# Spinner with Text and Icons

Tags: android, text, icons, spinner

In my app, I have a `Spinner`, that can be filled with two `Array`s of `Strings`, stored in my `values/strings.xml` resource. Depending on the state of two RadioButtons, the values from the correct Array is selected and my Spinner gets filled.

For each Array of Strings, I have an Array of Icons which have the same size. All of my icons start with an "A" and are followed by a number. I can't change this, it's stored like that in the database. I have an Array in Strings.xml with all the numbers I require to draw the icons. All the actual icons can be found in the `drawable` resource folder.

Now I want to show the corresponding item next to the String from the list which was selected by the Spinner. When an item gets selected, I just need to see the text.

I have searched the Internet for a good tutorial, but with what I have found I have not succeeded in doing this. I'm just beginning in Android programming so I think I need a little help. I hope that somebody can guide me in the right direction.

I put my String Array within actual Arrays, such as:

```
// Arrays with each function in text
arbeiderjobs = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.arbeiders);
bediendejobs = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.bediende);

// Arrays with each function ID
arbeiderjobsid = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.arbeidersid);
bediendejobsid = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.bediendeid);
```

When one of the RadioButtons gets selected, I use the following event handler code:

```
// RadioButton 'Arbeider': If a value gets chosen in this list, 
// the corresponding ID is put in the below variable 
RadioButton rbArbeider = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rbArbeider);
rbArbeider.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() 
{
  public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) 
  {
    if (isChecked)
    {
      showSpinner(arbeiderjobs, R.id.cmbFuncties);
      s.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() 
      {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, 
                                   View selectedItemView, int position, long id)
        {
          functie = arbeiderjobsid[position];
          statuut = 1;
          visible = false;  
        }
      });

      visible = true;
    }
  } // s.setOnItemSelectedListener

}); // rbArbeider.setOnCheckedChangeListener
```

This is my `showSpinner` method:

```
private void showSpinner(String [] jobs, int id)
{    
  MyCustomAdapter adapter = new MyCustomAdapter
  (
    FindJob.this, 
    R.layout.spinnerrow, 
    jobs
  );

  adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

  for (int i = 0; i < jobs.length; i++)
  {
    adapter.add(jobs[i]);
  }

  Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById(id);
  s.setClickable(true);
  s.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

I've made a custom adapter based on [this tutorial](http://android-er.blogspot.de/2010/06/custom-arrayadapter-with-with-different.html), but I'm kind of tangled in it... I need some help:

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{

  public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, 
                         String[] objects) 
  {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
  }

  @Override
  public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
  {
    return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent, 
                         arbeiderjobs, arbeiderjobsid);
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
  {
    return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent, 
                         arbeiderjobs, arbeiderjobsid);
  }

  public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent,                                                         
                            String jobs[], int jobsid[]) 
  {
    // return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinnerrow, parent, false);
    TextView label = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.functie);
    label.setText(jobs[position]);

    ImageView icon = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.icon);

    String uri = "@drawable/a" + jobsid[position];
    int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier
    (  
      uri, 
      null, 
      getPackageName()
    );
    icon.setImageResource(imageResource);

    if (visible)
    {
      icon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    return row;
  }

}
```

This is what I would want it to look like:

[image: Result]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to implement a custom Adapter and define a custom layout for the list items. [Check this tutorial](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/12/custom-arrayadapter-for-spinner-with.html).

**UPDATE**

Try the following. I haven't tested the code but I think it should work like that.

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    private String[] mIcons;

    public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
    String[] objects, String[] icons) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        mIcons = icons;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

       LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
       View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinnerrow, parent, false);
       TextView label=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.functie);
       label.setText(getItem(position);

       ImageView icon=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.icon);

       String uri = "@drawable/a" + mIcons[position];
       int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, getPackageName());
       icon.setImageResource(imageResource);

       return row;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, a linearlayout with the text and the icon, a custom adapter, and a couple of getText() and setText() accessory methods. There's another thorough tutorial (for lists, but the same concept) here: http://www.anddev.org/iconified_textlist_-_the_making_of-t97.html

Comment: I've tried the tutorial, but I'm still kind of tangled with my two Arrays... would you mind helping me? Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: What is the problem at the moment? As I can see in you edited question, you're already accessing both array from within your adapter. label.setText(jobs[position]); and String uri = "@drawable/a" + jobsid[position];

Comment: I don't know how to pass the array with icons to the arrayadapter. I can pass one array, put not two... When I run this code I get the following error: http://pastebin.com/5JRPEnLt

Comment: I had come very close to your answer and I implemented the missing pieces you showed in your example. Too bad it still gives some errors: http://pastebin.com/RAq7wwy9

Comment: Can you debug your code to see when exactly the exception occurs.

Comment: He can't seem to get around this line `label.setText(getItem(position));`

Comment: I've also removed the for-clause in my showSpinner method and I'm getting another exception: http://pastebin.com/21pMsWrf

Comment: Can you check what you get from getItem(position)? Perhaps it's not a string so you might have to cast or tranform it.

Comment: it keeps 'pending', with a `system.out.println` I could see the first Item of the array

Comment: What do you mean with "pending"? Just add a line 'String dummy = getItem(position);' and check the value of the dummy variable.

Comment: it contains the first string of my array

Comment: Mh weird, then I don't understand how label.setText(getItem(position);
could throw an exception.

Comment: Perhaps you should start over again by implementing a custom adapter which only uses one array and your custom item layout. When you got it working you start to extend it step by step to a two array adapter.

Comment: I've started completly over and I have solved the problem. First of all, I had to make a new integer array on top, in the `ShowSpinner` method, I had to pass the array and put it in the new integer array. The `Custom Adapter Class` remains the same like in the tutorial + putting the 'a' in front of each item in my new integer array.

Comment: Do you have an idea to show the images only when the spinner opens the list? I have tried to put a boolean in my `setOnItemSelectedListener` from the Spinner and did `icon.setVisibility(View.GONE);`in the CustomAdapter class, but the icon still shows when selected.

Comment: I think you have to implement this behavior in the getView() method of you adapter. At the moment getView() and getDropDownView() both call getCustomView(), so the items always look the same regardless if the spinner is in drop down mode or not. So in your case each of the both methods needs its own implementation. getDropDownView() can simply call the getCustomView() method, but in the getView() method you have to hide the icon.

Comment: If I understand well, I have to implement `if(visible){ icon.setVisibility(View.GONE); }` in the getView method... but I have a feeling that's not enough...

Comment: No you don't need the if-statement as you always want to return a View with a hidden icon if the spinner is not in drop down mode. If it is in drop down mode getDropDownView() is called instead of getView().