# ActionBar spinner with an icon (like Google Maps), how can I achieve that?

Tags: android, navigation, icons, spinner, android-actionbar

I am currently trying, in addition of the amazing ActionBerSherlock library to add a spinner  navigation menu in my application (like Google Maps)

Note: I have been thinking also about the SPotify/Evernote/Facebook pattern, but that seems inappropriate on Android: http://alexanderblom.se/2012/04/23/android-navigation-and-spotify/

[image]

I have already worked on the spinner (http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/spinners.html), but adding an icon seems not so easy

Thank a lot for any link or help on this menu...

Comment: Full Working code is here: https://github.com/iRail/BeTrains-for-Android/blob/f5ae21c32218578d7d5f257344e92f5a1f27b1f0/src/tof/cv/mpp/Activity/BeTrainsActivity.java

Answer (score 2):

First you need to create a CustomArrayAdapter for your spinner. It should handle both, an array of Strings and an array of Drawables. In your case perhaps a second array for a little summary.

Then you'll need a layout for the item with the ImageView for the icon and a TextView for the text (and perhaps one for the summary). Override the getView() and the getDropDownView() to fill your layout with the resources handed in (createFromResource() might be a method to look into).

For the Navigation, all you need to do is to create the CustomArrayAdapter in your onCreate() with the arrays of resources, call MyActionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST) and feed the Navigation with your CustomArrayAdapter via MyActionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(list, this).

Comment: ArrayAdapter was not the perfect ID as it always crashed, asking for a TextView.. I used a BaseAdapter and everything is fine. Thank a lot for your kind help.

Comment: An UpVote or Acceptance of my answer would be awesome.

Comment: Upvoted ;-)sorry, but I accepted my answer, as the full source code is there and will be the best help for someone asking same question...

Comment: i'm actually trying to figure out the same thing, can you post code as an example?

Comment: here is a nice example of how to do this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/5744293/1094784

Answer (score 0):

One would assume that one would use the Android `Adapter` pattern, with that adapter containing a list, of sorts (perhaps an `ArrayList`?), of the items that you want to display (in this case, an icon, a title string and a subtitle string).

Take a look at extending some sort of `SpinnerAdapter`; presumably you'll also then need to create a layout for each item that contains both the icon and the two `TextView`s.