# How to add text into spinner?

Tags: android, spinner

I have created a spinner at the header of a listview. How do I add text into it? I would like to show the text in the spinnerText.

```
String[] spinnerText = { "Sort by date posted (latest to oldest)", "Sort by price (lowest to highest)"};
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View spinTop = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spin, null);
    getListView().addHeaderView(spinTop);
```

Comment: Dup. : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5744065/spinner-with-text-and-icons?rq=1

Comment: is there other way without creating adapter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use an `ArrayAdapter<String>` as follows:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,spinnerText);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinTop.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Also you'll have to cast `spinTop`:

```
Spinner spinTop = (Spinner) inflater.inflate(R.layout.spin, null);
```

Comment: Already cast the spinTop but i am having this error: The method setAdapter(ArrayAdapter<String>) is undefined for the type View

Comment: Declare `spinTop` as a `Spinner`, not as a `View`.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to use an ArrayAdapter like this :

```
spinTop.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerText));
```